# How do I get an image from the user's gallery and then convert it to bitmap and then use it to generate a color palette?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-jetpack, color-palette

**Note: Most answers that I could find here on stack overflow were either outdated (and used deprecated methods) or were closely related but not exactly useful for my case**

I am making an app that generates a color palette from the image input by the user. I am using [this Jetpack library](https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors)
to achieve this. I am very much a noob and have never dealt with Bitmaps or such intents before. I believe the code to launch an image picker should be like below:

```
const val PICK_IMAGE = 1

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var openGalleryButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        openGalleryButton = findViewById(R.id.open_gallery_button)
        openGalleryButton.setOnClickListener {
            val photoPickerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            photoPickerIntent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE)
        }
    }

}
```

Then I guess I have to do override `onActivityResult()` and do something there? But no matter what I do, I can't get it working. I am NOT looking to set this image to any `ImageView` and most answers to similar problems only answer how to set the image to an `ImageView` or are outdated and use deprecated methods.

I want to get the image from the user when they press the button, somehow convert it to a Bitmap that can be used inside with the color palette library. Get the dominant colors from the generated palette as hex color or some other usable format and deal with it myself.

Comment: Yes. In onActivityResult open an InputStream for the obtained uri. Then use BitmapFactory.decodeStream to create a bitmap.

Comment: @blackapps can you tell me a little bit more about how to open an input stream?

Comment: getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()); Now first post your onActivityResult code in a new code block  if you have further questions.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. Are there any alternatives though? I think it's kind of hacky to use an input stream since it feels completely unrelated to the problem. I am a complete noob and don't know anything so please feel free to tell me I am completely wrong.

Comment: I do not understand your doubts. To create a bitmap the code i proposed is THE way to go. What you wanna do with the bitmap is something else.

Comment: No no, I am not saying thats not the right way. its just weird how many solutions there are out there but none of them really work. How do I know if I should use this one or some other one on the internet. Your solution was the only one that worked

Comment: Much code on the internet is old and does not run on newer osses. See is there is a publication date.

Comment: I found this one too. I haven't tried it but is using a cursor a good idea? I don't even know what a cursor is really, I have never dealt with it. https://pastebin.com/XjX9J84a

Comment: No. That does not even come close to the two lines you have now and will not work on Android 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question was answered by @blackapps and the solution to this problem is to start an input stream with content resolver by passing in the image URI. After you get the URI, decode the stream with bitmap factory and then that would return you your bitmap.

```
val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(selectedImageUri)
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SvenWoltmann/color-thief-java

Here is some logic that may be useful for your project.
Simple code snippet:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();

var sourceImage = document.getElementById("image");

// Display main color
// e.g [125, 189, 193]
console.log(
    colorThief.getColor(sourceImage)
);

// Display palette of colors
// e.g [[55,37,29],[213,193,136],[110,204,223]]
console.log(
    colorThief.getPalette(sourceImage)
);
```

Or you can use Vibrant, a JavaScript port of a popular Java library:

http://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/

Comment: I tried reading that code but I really don't understand it. i feel like its too advanced for me.

Comment: @SbeveSbren please check code snippet I added

Comment: I am sorry if this is a dumb question but is color thief a library? Do I add this library to my project?